# left outer join over three tables?

Tags: sql, oracle, left-join

I am trying to make sense of an Oracle SQL query that has this structure:

```
select * from A, B, C
where
A.Col1 = B.Col1(+) and
C.Col1= A.Col1 (+)
```

I am not used to the deprecated (+) syntax, so I would apreciate if someone could provide an ANSI translation of the query. Or an explanation in words.

**Edit:**

Polppan´s answer is probably right. I am not sure (and neither is he it seems) since I cannot verify it somehow and still don't fully understand the (+) syntax.

The following query seems to be equivalent to Polppan´s answer, and for me it's easier to map it to the first query due to that the order of the joins are kept:

```
 SELECT * 
  FROM A
  LEFT JOIN B ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
  RIGHT JOIN C ON C.Col1 = A.Col1
```

If someone else can provide an answer that provides an ANSI translation along with an explanation, I would gladly mark that as the answer avoid the current uncertainties.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use the following ANSI query, change select columns as per your wish.

```
SELECT *
  FROM C
       LEFT OUTER JOIN A
          ON C.Col1 = A.Col2
       LEFT OUTER JOIN B
          ON A.Col1 = B.Col1
```

[This](http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/) article explains `sql joins` eloquently.